# UITabBar Selected Item Tint Color

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uicolor, tintcolor, bartintcolor

I'm working on an UITabBar-Application.

I want to change the selected Item Color with

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]
```

This works, until I want to set the Background Color of the TabBar with

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]]
```

Then the Bar is blue, but the highlighted Items are grey.

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]
```

has no effect. 
Any Idea?
Thank you very much!

Comment: instead of using color you can try background with images.

Comment: Thank you - background with images worked by another App. But I made now the Icons in two colors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, that you've posted, seems to be working. You can do it with images too. Try this:

```
[tabBarItem1 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem1 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_selected.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

// Change the tab bar background
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selected.png"]];
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I did now. I set de background still with a UIColor, but have selected and non-selected Icons

Answer (score 3):

Try this Code

```
//Set greenColor for normal State
[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
        UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor greenColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//Set purpleColor for normal State  


[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
        UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor purpleColor] }     forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Hope this helps.